# Help To create Folder1/Folder2 in Windows using VBScript ( Both the folders not exists before, i mean to create multilevel folders @ a strech.)

Tags: windows, scripting, vbscript

I have created folders using my VBscript. when i give a folder path, the script is creating only the last folder, if the last but one folder does not exists, it will fail... I need a vbscript code to create the entire folder structure on the single go. like mkdir -p in unix

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You could use this function:

```
Const PATH = "X:\folder0\folder1\folder2"

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

BuildFullPath PATH

Sub BuildFullPath(ByVal FullPath)
    If Not fso.FolderExists(FullPath) Then
        BuildFullPath fso.GetParentFolderName(FullPath)
        fso.CreateFolder FullPath
    End If
End Sub
```

Or simply call the mkdir command from your script:

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
objShell.Run "cmd /c mkdir X:\folder1\folder2\folder3"
```

Comment: To make it work with relative paths, the conditional can be changed to `If path <> "" and not objFSO.FolderExists(path)`

Comment: @VijayAthreyan, shouldn't you accept the answer, since it is correct?

Comment: @Pascal Rodriguez, the second option works, but if you make the directory structure a parameter you create a vulnerability where the caller can inject a shell command, isn't it?

Comment: Option 2 has to contend with spaces in the folder name so it needs to be enclosed in quotes ... something like this should be done:   Shell.Run "cmd /c mkdir """ & PATH & """"

Answer (score 10):

You must split the full path and create each folder.
Example function:

```
Function CreateFolderRecursive(FullPath)
  Dim arr, dir, path
  Dim oFs

  Set oFs = WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  arr = split(FullPath, "\")
  path = ""
  For Each dir In arr
    If path <> "" Then path = path & "\"
    path = path & dir
    If oFs.FolderExists(path) = False Then oFs.CreateFolder(path)
  Next
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks. This is great.

Answer (score 2):

Late to the show, but the Shell.Application object works for me in XP, as follows ...

```
with CreateObject("Shell.Application")
  set oFolder = .NameSpace("C:\")
  if (not oFolder is nothing) then oFolder.NewFolder("a\b\c\d")
end with
```