# Create a folder in a 2012 windows server from application published in another 2012 windows server

Tags: permissions, asp-classic, windows-server-2012, iis-8.5

Below is the classic asp code that raises "Permission Denied" error on trying to create a folder in a 2012 windows server from application published in another 2012 windows server. The windows server has IIS 8.5 and the application pool is integrated 4.0 with identity as ApplicationPoolIdentity.

```
Dim oFS, oF
Set oFS = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If Not oFS.FolderExists(basefolder) Then
    Set oF = oFS.CreateFolder(basefolder)
    Set oF = Nothing
End If
Set oFS = Nothing
```

Here basefolder is the path in which the new folder is to be created.
Any suggestions to make it work would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you given the IUSR account associated with your website write permission on the folder which will contain the folder you're trying to create

Comment: Yes. I have given "Full access" permission for the Domain account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something to try:

Create a domain account that has permissions on the server where you want to create the folder. Also give it permissions to the website root folder on the server that is running the website.

Then change the website's application pool to run as that account (Application Pool -> Advanced Settings -> Process Model -> Identity).

Comment: Raised a IT request to create a new domain account. Will keep you posted if that worked!

Comment: I gave access to the root folder in which the web application is published and access to the root folders and sub folders in which I am creating a file and running the application pool with the domain account. still no success

Comment: Something else to try: in IIS manager -> website settings -> Authentication -> right-click Anonymous Authentication ->  Edit... -> set Specific user to the domain account you created.

Comment: Also check the value of your baseFolder variable. The createFolder method won't create multiple folders in a path. For that you'd have to use something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4407468/989516

Comment: The createFolder method is creating only one folder at a time. Still not able to figure out the issue.

Comment: Is baseFolder a unc path?

Comment: Try loggin on to the IIS machine using the domain account you created that IIS is running as, and then try to access the other machine using whatever path is in baseFolder.

Comment: baseFolder is a UNC path.

Comment: I am able to access the UNC shared path by RDP into the IIS machine using the domain server account

Comment: Just to be sure, you can you create a folder at the desired location when logged in to the web server with that account?

Comment: "Here basefolder is the path in which the new folder is to be created." Just to be sure, does basefolder include the existing parent folder and end with the name of the new folder to be created?

Comment: @NagarajRaveendran wanted to check whether you tried this: In IIS manager -> website settings -> Authentication -> right-click Anonymous Authentication -> Edit... -> set Specific user to the domain account you created.

Comment: Yes, when I log into desired location with domain account it does allow me to create a folder. No, the parent and to be created folders have different names.

Comment: I have noticed that might help answer the question. If I open the server where the application is published with the domain account I could not open the server in IIS. Is that have to do something with the issue?

Comment: @NagarajRaveendran that is interesting. Could you try this:  In IIS manager -> website settings -> Authentication -> right-click Anonymous Authentication -> Edit... -> set Specific user to the domain account you created.

Comment: This is an intranet application and we use windows authentication which the applications uses to get NT user information. I am not sure if we can have anonymous authentication enabled.

Comment: Do the user accounts authenticating to the web server have access to the target folder?

Comment: @NagarajRaveendran if the user accounts don't have access to the target folder, something else to try: In IIS manager, open Configuration Editor. Under Section, select “system.webServer/serverRuntime”. Select UseWorkerProcessUser. (The default value is UseAuthenticatedUser).